# How to populate a custom column with xml in woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom column with a custom plugin.

I dont know if I can use the following to populate this column with a value from an xml.

```
//POPULATE COLUMN
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'wnetpp_populate_custom_columns3', 10, 2);
function wnetpp_populate_custom_columns3( $column, $post_id ) {

  if ($column == 'test_column3') {
        $current_product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
        $product_sku = $current_product->get_sku();

   read_parse_xml($product_sku)

}    }
```

and with a function like the following:

```
function read_parse_xml($product_sku)
{   
   $url = 'https://example.com/ProductsUpdates4.xml';
   $xml = file_get_contents($url);
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

   foreach($xml as $x) {
          $sku = $x->sku;
      $bfsku = $x->bf_sku;
          $suppliersku = $x->supplier_sku;
          $price = $x->price;
          $availability = $x->availability;

      if($sku==$product_sku)
          {
            echo '<div id="_supprice-' . $post_id . '">' . $price .  '</div>';
          }

   }

}
```

But nothing is working.

I get a blank page for products.

How I am supposed to check if xml has been accessed.

Answer (score 0):

First I forgot to put a semicolumn ; after  read_parse_xml($product_sku)

For each column I created a different read_parse_xml($product_sku) function called read_parse_xml1 2 3 etc.

and I used number_format to format my string to Number like

```
  if($sku==$product_sku)
      {
        echo '<div id="_supprice-' . $post_id . '">' . number_format( (float)$price,2) . € .  '</div>';

      }
```

Even though I dont know if there is another proper way with less code to do it, it worked for me